# Hide sender email address when sending email

Tags: excel, vba, email, cdo.message

I want a VBA method to display only **sender name** in email when recipient sees my email, like so:

[image]

But it displays both **sender name** and **address** like below:

[image]

Is there any solution to hide sender address in email through Excel VBA?

Comment: I believe that is determined by the presence of the address in the local contacts list, which of course you cannot control.

Comment: I think, there must be something to control local contacts ! any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide an email address which is not it the local address list from showing up, but if the recipient is in the same organization (same domain/server), and use a shared global address list, it might be possible to have the contact available to anyone, thus showing the contact from the global list.

Comment: Yes, the recipient is in the same organization (same server), but how to know that address list is shared or not ? and what will be possibility if list is shared.

Comment: You need to confirm this with your mailserver admin, and ask for instructions on configuring the shared catalog based on the mail server software. Please note that the configuration of the client at the recipient end might be a hassle greater than just adding the address to the local address list manually.

Comment: Thanks, for all of your contribution but I got my answer and it is very simple to hide only sender ID. I just need to use comma (**,**) between name & ID in my code then recipient cannot see my sender address on his screen except sender name when I use this trick `.From = """username"",<email@abc.com>"`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for all of your contribution but I got my answer and it is very simple to hide only **sender ID**. I just need to use *comma* (**,**) between **name** & **ID** in my code, like so:

```
.To = "sam@abc.com" 
.CC = ""  
.BCC = ""
.From = """username"",<email@abc.com>" 
.Subject = "test"
.TextBody = ""
.send
```

Then recipient cannot see my **sender address**  on his screen except **sender name** when I use this trick `.From = """username""`**,**`<email@abc.com>"`. **:)**